# segfault R package check

Tags: r, segmentation-fault, package

I am updating a package [qdap](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/qdap/index.html) that [had a single note on CRAN in its previous build](http://cran.r-project.org/web/checks/check_results_qdap.html), which was resolved.

In the [qdap development version](https://github.com/trinker/qdap), under R 2.15.3, using `--as-cran` and `--resave-data=best`, I get the following note:

```
* checking R code for possible problems ... NOTE
Segmentation fault
```

Why is this segfault occurring (I'm somewhat new to Linux)?  How can I find it?  I googled this for sometime but I couldn't figure out what the problem is.  I gather there's some sort of problem in my code but...

On Windows I get no notes.

I can provide more info if needed (though the GitHub repo is available).

**Session Info:**

```
R version 2.15.3 (2013-03-01)
Platform: i686-pc-linux-gnu (32-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=C                 LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] pacman_0.2.0 XML_3.9-4   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_2.15.3
```

Comment: Is it okay that what you're referring to as 3.0.0 prints 2.15.3 as its version number?

Comment: Yes mistake in typing, I used 3.0.0 on windows. Fixed it, Thank you.

Comment: FWIW, doesn't crash for me on either trunk or 2.15.3, 64 bit Debian unstable.